# Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.193, Visual Studio 2017 and java code 2

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

yesterday I installed Visual Studio 2017. Amazing! I opened my Xamarin project, very simple project, and now I can't deploy the Android project because I have an

> "java.exe" exited with code 2

I understood this error occurs when the app exceeds the limit memory for an app but before with Visual Studio 2015 the app was working fine.

[image: Java code 2]

Now in the Solution Explorer a lot of Xamarin components related to Android are in warning.

[image: Solution Explorer]

If I try to reinstall all packages with

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

I receive a lot of error because the namespace `Xamarin` could not be found.

[image: Xamarin could not be found]

I opened another Xamarin Forms project and now for the Android project I have this errors:

[image: Other project error]

If I try to update the packages, Package Manager Console shows this message:

> One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the
>   existing packages.config file. All dependency constraints must be
>   resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being
>   updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may
>   be blocking the current package operation: 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193
>   constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms
>   2.3.3.193 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193 constraint:
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms
>   2.3.3.193 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193 constraint:
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)',
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Maps 2.3.3.193 constraint:
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps (= 29.0.0.1)', 'Xamarin.Forms.Maps
>   2.3.3.193 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms.Maps 2.3.3.193 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)'
>
> Update-Package :
>   Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
>   25.1.1' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms.Maps 2.3.3.193 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)'. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Update-Package -Reinstall
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
>
> Time Elapsed: 00:00:32.7114587

[image: Update error message]

What can I do now?

Comment: Try, updating Xamarin with latest, Open the Android SDK manager and make sure you have the latest SDK and Tools. Then update these packages. Do a clean/rebuild and should work.

Comment: I did everything but it doesn't work

Comment: Remove all reference and start adding them back. You can start adding the Xamarin.Android.Support.Design as this will add most of the others.

Comment: I discovered the problem. I created another project and I started to add all components. The component responsible is `Google Play Services - Ads` ver. 42.1001.0.0. I added it from `Xamarin Store`. Now the question is how I can add it without errors.

Comment: @Enrico Look at SO question 44004161 that is what answered it for me