# Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.193 and ads

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with advertisement for iOS and Android. I'm creating a cross platform app I should insert some advertisement. For this reason I created a component in the main project and in each platform project I render it with the right components.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.193.

**iOS**

For iOS I added `Firebase AdMob for iOS (7.15.0.1)` and its dependencies.

[image: iOS]

When I compile the project I receive an error

> Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(38,3): error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image: Visual Studio iOS]

It is the same error if I update this component to version 0.4.2

**Android**

In Android I added `Google Play Services` ver. 42.1001.0.0, I receive an error from `java.exe` (I described this error in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668779/xamarin-forms-2-3-3-193-visual-studio-2017-and-java-code-2))

> java code 2

I tried to update everything but the result is exactly the same. If I removed all `Xamarin.GooglePlayService` and I install `Google Play Services` ver. 29.0.0.2 the app is working fine without any errors.

For both project I created a new cross platform project and I added all components until I found the error came from the ads.

Any suggestions? Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can install a prelease of the `Xamarin.Build` with this command:

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Build.Download -Version 0.4.3-beta1 -Pre
```

For Android you can install `Google Play Services` ver. 29.0.0.2